# HMR is not reloading on changes outside /src

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, react-boilerplate, hot-module-replacement

I have a shared folder where reusable React components are stored. I want to make Hot Reload working with that directory, but it doesn't work. 
Here is the folder structure I have:

```
|__shared
|__src
|__package.json
```

Somehow Webpack HotModuleReplacement plugin is not triggering re-load when something is changing in a `/shared` folder? 
The entry in webpack.config looks like this:

```
entry: [
  "eventsource-polyfill",
  "webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true",
  path.join(process.cwd(), "src/app.js"),
]
```

Hot in the app:

```
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      console.log('done')
    })
  }
```

The app is bootstrapped with `react-boilerplate`.

Comment: I use `webpack-dev-server` for hot reloading. Do an `npm install` of the package and add a script like this to your `package.json` - `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot"`. If you run `npm run dev` on your terminal, your app should update every time you make a change.

Comment: Can you provide all code that is in app.js please?